# Why return -1 instead of 0?

Tags: c#

Recently I have noticed a convention for assigning an id for a particular entity and what took my attention was the return of -1 if the id is not there. Why return -1 instead of 0?

```
protected long AcqAgreementID
{            
    get
    {
        if(ViewState["AcqAgreementID"] != null)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt64(ViewState["AcqAgreementID"]);
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In some contexts 0 is a valid value

Comment: Is my question looks so stupid that i get minus.

Comment: if by returning -1 or 0 you want to show an error occurred, you should go ahead with -1. Returning 0 instead or any other value as error code means, your blocked exited without any error. It was just an old best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often 0 is a valid id or return value. Think of a control that has indexes or searching in a string. When looking for a selected index for a control that holds multiple items or when looking for the index of a certain char in a string, a return value of 0 is perfectly normal. Index 0 means the first item selected or a char is found at the first position in the string. In both cases -1 is returned when nothing has been selected or found.

Comment: I like your answer very much.Simple and sweet.Thanks bro.

Answer (score 7):

I expect that -1 was chosen because that value can never be used for an ID. In which case it can be used to signal that the ID is invalid.

It would seem that the designer of this function intended callers to check whether or not the return value is the special sentinel value -1. If -1 is returned, then the caller is expected to take appropriate steps. For example, the caller may show or log an error message.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Then why not  0 ?

Comment: @HumayounKabir Only the author of the code could answer that. Perhaps 0 is a valid ID. Perhaps not. Even if 0 is invalid, -1 is more obviously a bad value. Plus the value of -1 is very frequently used to indicate an invalid array index and so perhaps the familiarity of that use case spilled over into this one.

Comment: 0 is the default value for integer structures.  It could be difficult to determine if the property is not set or invalid.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard for methods that return an index in the `.NET` framework.

> `public int FindIndex(    Predicate<T> match )` method returns the
>   zero-based index of the first occurrence of an element that matches
>   the conditions defined by match, if found; otherwise, –1.

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx)

This is so the caller can handle the ID/index not being found any way that they want. They may throw an exception or by getting the ID from another source; whatever they want.

Nullable types *could've* be used, instead, but the standard for these methods was developed before the introduction of nullable types. If you have control over this code, you may consider changing it, but there's nothing wrong with returning -1. Definitely don't return 0, because 0 is often a valid ID/index.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you should return neither.   Most likely you should throw an exception.

Returning 0 or -1 means that the calling program has to check for this known bad value instead of simply catching the exception.

Comment: I disagree. I see two cases 1)If the application expects a non zero value, throwing an exception is fine. But it shouldn't be caught in that case. 2) The calling code needs to handle a missing value. In that case it should check if it's valid. (Perhaps using a `TryGetAgreementID` method). Don't use exception handling for control flow.

Comment: From the code sample given, this looks like an application exception.

Comment: I agree that exceptions should not be used for flow control

From the code sample given, this looks like an application exception.

Throwing an Exception allows you to provide  more context and help.   Instead of returning 0 or -1, throwing a custom exception allows you explicitly state what was going on.   You could throw an AcqAgreementIDNotSetExcption to indicate that the ViewState value was null or an AcqAgreementIDWrongFormatException to indicate that the value retrieved from ViewState was in the wrong format.

Also exceptions will be logged & tracked.

Comment: @Nick: There will be no exception to be handled because this id field is the primary key field for those entity and it's value type is bigint[sql database] and it is auto incremented.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple case of [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) anti pattern.

It should not be done. Consts or defines (depending on the language) should be used.

Magic numbers in general; cause WTFs and questions just like yours.

Comment: I would upvote if you would add the possibility of throwing an exception in case of invalid calls.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit open ended and somehow too general; it is really easy to answer with something like "it depends".
In general, you use negative values when 0 is a perfectly legit domain value (it is in the allowed range for IDs, for example)

It is not a good pattern to use, however: it leaves users of the function/API confused (like you). You have to figure out that the function returns numbers in one domain (positive integers) and that a negative value is impossible, and therefore used as an "invalud" valude.

In C#/.NET for example you should consider Nullable types. They explicitly say "this value is not in the domain" by adding an extra "value/state" (null).
Besides nullable types, other valid conventions you should consider are:

- throw an exception (like for Int.Parse)
- add an `out` parameter to indicate validity or not (like Int.TryParse)

Comment: Nullables can create a mess on their own.  I agree with your "it depends"... but that is then countered by "should use nullable"... that is again an "it depends".

Comment: @MatthewWhited right, I edited it to "should consider". Nullable types, and NULL in relational DBs before, where invented for this purpose (have a non-domain value for conditions where there is an error/a non-initialized condition)

Comment: @dema80: This id field can't be nullable integer because it is primary key field for that entity.

Comment: @HumayounKabir if you cannot change the return type, consider one of the other two methods I mentioned. I was answering in a general way, considering all the alternatives. Mind you, even using "-1" is not "wrong", per se. It makes code less clear, IMO, but many functions/framework follow this convention after all

Comment: If you go with "-1", consider at least "marking" it explicitly, like for example `string::npos` in the STL (which is actually -1).

Answer (score 0):

I have used this pattern in places where I wanted to use a non-nullable integer value for an ID.  I did not like using 0 as the "default"/"unassigned" ID since it is the default value of integer types.  This allows me to look at model objects be determine if they should be insert or update and I can also tell if it unknown "0".

It depends on your architecture and as you see from several of the other posts it can build a religious war over nullable v. non-nullable IDs.

...

As a note I've also seen/used patterns where the model had a nullable type that was colleased (??) with known value such as -1 before a call into a function/data model that required non-nullable types.  It is the awesome world of “it depends” that we always get into on development projects.